# Conversion function in asp to Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I'm trying to write asp-classic function in Javascript... but i can't seem to get it right... can someone help?

ASP:

```
Dim i
Dim sAscii

sAscii = ""
For i = 1 To Len(str)
    sAscii = sAscii + "&#" + CStr(Asc(Mid(str, i, 1))) + ";"
Next

ascconv= sAscii
```

javascript:

```
var i;
 str1 = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
var sAscii1;

i = 0;
sAscii1 = "";

for(i; i = str1.length; i++) {
    sAscii1 = sAscii1 + "&#" + str1.charCodeAt(i) + ";"; 
}

document.getElementById('firstname').innerHTML = sAscii1;
```

Comment: *"but i can't seem to get it right... can someone help?"* We can't tell you what you did wrong (and provide solutions) if you don't post your result.

Comment: Are you talking about server side ASP/JScript or client side JavaSCript?

Comment: Sorry Felix.  Just posted what i did in javascript.

Comment: And how do you know it's not "right"? What is the problem with the code you posted? What is the code supposed to do anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert this function in javascript you have to do something like this:

```
var i,str1 = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
var sAscii1 = "";

for(var i=0; i < str1.length; i++) {
    sAscii1 = sAscii1 + "&#" + str1.charCodeAt(i) + ";"; 
}

document.getElementById('firstname').value = sAscii1;//I think you made a mistake here...as you have a input variable you will get/set the value and not innerHTML
```

where charCodeAt is similar to Asc (converts to ascii code)

Answer (score 0):

```
var i, sAscii = "", str = "This is a string";

for(i = 0; i < str.length; a++){
    sAscii += "&#" + str[a].charCodeAt(0) + ";";
}
```

Comment: Friendly advice: Add an **explanation** to your solutions.